# Create a parallax auto scroll background in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, scroll, phaser-framework

I am using phaser 3 to build a parallax auto side scroll space game (like, R-type, for example).

The background is supposed to scroll by it self, but the phaser 2.3 commands does not seem to work with phaser 3, such as tileSprites. Anyone knows of a workaround or solution for phaser 3 to make this happen?

What I have now, is a phaser 2.3 solutions, and I want to do it in Phaser 3, but that does not work. I am new to Phaser so maybe I am missing something here. Thanks!

```
    function preload() {
    game.load.image("background", "assets/backgrounds/background.png");
}

function create() {
    this.tileSprite = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, "background");
    this.tileSprite.autoscroll(-100, 0);
}

function update() {

}
```

Comment: Haven't tested it, but it appears that `autoscroll` may not yet be in Phaser 3. http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/36524-tilesprite-for-parallax/ has an example workaround.

Comment: Thanks James, I figured it, but you are right, does not seem to have support for autoscroll yet. Thanks for the workaround tip, will check it out!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to load your image in preload method of your scene:

```
preload() {
    game.load.image("background", "assets/backgrounds/background.png");
}
```

then to use it just do this in the create method of your scene:

```
//the width and height value could be the screen width and height
//"background" is the name of your preloaded image
this.background = this.add.tileSprite(0, 0, width, height, "background")
    .setOrigin(0)
    .setScrollFactor(0, 1); //this line keeps your background from scrolling outside of camera bounds
```

and finally in the update method of your scene add this line scroll your tiled background image to create an endless runner background effect:

```
this.background.setTilePosition(this.cameras.main.scrollX);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for the past 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.tileSprite.tilePositionX += 100;` in update method to move the background.
https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.TileSprite.html